# git-am --keep-cr not effective on LFS tracked files?

Tags: git, git-lfs

Let’s say, we have some dev teams spread in the world, and there is a Git repo with lots of legacy code, including large XML files (actually databases, containing diverse data with mixed newlines).
There is some data exchange between loosely attached teams, which happened using Git Patches (git format-patch ...).
This has worked for a while, however the party who received the patches had to use `git am --keep-cr ...`, without `--keep-cr` it failed with obscure `patch does not apply` messages, although when we tested it originally, `git apply --check ...` was happy, only `git-am`was not.

Now a new stakeholder enters the game. They use another local git repo mirror, which needs to receive the changes. The only difference is that this time the repo was configured with Git-LFS for performance considerations.
Result: `git am --keep-cr` method does NOT work there. It fails again with obscure issues, like:

```
$ git am --keep-cr 0001-feature-X.patch
warning: quoted CRLF detected
error: patch failed: Config/platform.xml:5523
error: Config/platform.xml: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: Config/target.arxml:150
error: Config/target.xml: patch does not apply
…
```

But why? We checksummed the contents, the original files are identical. The very same command works fine in the old repos. It only does NOT work on LFS-tracked files.

Out of desperation, we brought a copy of `.git` data to the LFS using site, attached as another git remote source and tried cherry-picking. And then, the very same errors started appearing, in a cherry-pick. But there is no issue using a similar
cherry-pick in the original repo on a sandbox branch.

So what is wrong with LFS-tracked files, what makes git's patch processing so dumb when working on them, even ignore --keep-cr?

Answer (score 0):

This is a fundamental property of Git-LFS.  It's due to the way Git-LFS deliberately "cheats" on Git, fooling Git into storing small "pointer files" instead of the actual files.  The LFS wrappers achieve this by strategically lying to Git: at the time `git checkout` or `git switch` or any other command goes to copy a file from Git's index to the working tree, LFS sneaks in and copies the real file instead.  At the time `git add` goes to copy a file from the working tree to Git's index, LFS sneaks in and replaces that with a new pointer file, scheduling the real file to go to the LFS server.

The `git apply` command *can* work, provided you apply only to the *working tree* copy.  But other Git commands try to work with the index copy: they *assume* that the index copy is effectively identical to the working-tree copy (modulo minor issues like CRLF line endings).  They do this because it's more efficient and/or because they intend to commit the result, which requires that the index copy of the file contain the to-be-committed content.  When using Git-LFS wrappers over Git, redirected files never contain content that's even remotely similar.

Probably `git am` and other commands should be replaced by LFS wrappers as well, but that's a hard problem.